# Method of base class getting called

Tags: c++, derived-class

I have the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Base{
    void f(int x){
        cout<<"B";
    }
};
struct Derived: public Base {
    virtual void f(double x){
        cout<<"D";
    }
};

int main(){
Derived d;
int x = 5;
d.f(x);
Base *pb = &d;
pb->f(x);

}
```

It outputs: `DB`
Even though pb stores the pointer to the derived class. Why is the method of 
`Base` class getting called?

Comment: You're missing `virtual` on the base class method. You can't make a method virtual after the fact; it has to be that way from the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Declaring `Derived::f` virtual doesn't make `Base::f` virtual, hence when you call `f` on a pointer to `Base` then  `Base::f` is called.

You should declare the method `virtual` in `Base`. It will then be also `virtual` in `Derived`, you don't need to repeat `virtual` there. In `Derived` you should use the `override` specifier like this:

```
struct Base{
    virtual void f(int x){
        cout<<"B";
    }
};
struct Derived: public Base {
    void f(double x) override {
        cout<<"D";
    }
};
```

The `override` specifier helps to catch mistakes when the method does not actually `override` an inherited method. For example for the above you will get an error along the line of:

```
source>:10:10: error: 'void Derived::f(double)' marked 'override', but does not override
   10 |     void f(double x) override {
      |          ^
```

The parameter types must match when you want to override.

This code prints the expected `DD`:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    virtual void f(int x){
        std::cout << "B";
    }
};
struct Derived: public Base {
    void f(int x) override {
        std::cout << "D";
    }
};
```

---

Note that if you don't use `override` then such mistakes can go unnoticed. When the classes are defined like this:

```
struct Base{
    virtual void f(int x){
        std::cout<<"B";
    }
};
struct Derived: public Base {
    void f(double x) {
        std::cout<<"D";
    }
};
```

Then `Derived::f` does not override `Base::f`. It only hides it and the output would still be `DB`.

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3K7vh5vza)

Answer (score -1):

It prints D first because of your function call of derived class and then it prints B because you are simply calling the function of base class